# Автоматическое изменение свойства по Городу и Изменение идентификатора отправления

Tags: битрикс

На сайте 1С-Bitrix при смене оператором ИМ статусов заказа, автоматически выходит изменение свойства по Городу, также автоматически происходит Изменение идентификатора отправления. Почему так происходит? Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой.